# sometime getcount function returning 0 in firebase android

Tags: android, database, firebase

In my code, I am using getcount() function to get the child nodes in android using firebase. It giving me perfect value most of the time but sometimes it returns 0 value. I am not getting it how it returns 0.
Hence my code and firebase database is given below. Please help me...

**Code:-**

```
    DatabaseReference db = mfirebaseDb.getReference("Users").child("request");

    ChildEventListener child=new ChildEventListener() {


        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            long ss =dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
            {

                temp = ss + temp;

            }

            Bundle bu=new Bundle();
            bu.putLong("temp",temp);
        }
```

**Firebase Database:-**
[Firebase Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggmku.png)

Comment: Where are you checking the count and you get 0?

Comment: i am using the count to calculate order id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with these code :

```
DatabaseReference db = mfirebaseDb.getReference("Users").child("request");

db.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(){
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dss)
    {
        // TODO: Implement this method
        if (dss.exists()) {
            Integer total = 0;
            total = (int)dss.getChildrenCount();

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError derr)
    {
        // TODO: Implement this method
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "SOMETHING WENT WRONG " + derr.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: sir I am not getting this code can u please elaborate me

Comment: The about code is calculating the total requests by users.

Comment: Firstly we are getting the reference of child node and using getChildrenCount()   of that reference we are storing the total number of requests in the INTEGER total.

Comment: If you get any error using the above code feel free to comment.